# Assigning values to a data.table when using dot-dot

Tags: r, data.table

I want to substract a vector from multiple columns from my data.table by name. I use an approach with dot-dot and I cannot seem to wrap my head around why the last assignment does not work, because both expressions work just fine when evaluated alone. I have attached a reproducible example that should make the issue clear.

```
dt <- data.table("a_x" = rnorm(10),
           "b_x" = rnorm(10),
           "a_y" = rnorm(10),
           "b_y" = rnorm(10),
           "d" = rnorm(10)
           )

XIND <- names(dt) %like% "_x"

MAT <- matrix(dt[,d], nrow = dim(dt[,..XIND])[1], ncol = dim(dt[,..XIND])[2])
dt[,..XIND] <- dt[,..XIND] - MAT
```

Comment: You should really raise this with the `data.table` devs over on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option which feels more idiomatic to me:

```
dt <- data.table("a_x" = 1:10, "b_x" = 2:11, "d" = 1:10)
XIND <- grep("_x$", names(dt))
dt[, (XIND) := .SD - d, .SDcols=XIND]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `str_subset` as a workaround, which is, however, not ideal in my opinion.

```
dt[,(str_subset(names(dt),"_x"))] <- dt[,..XIND] - MAT
```